# Как определить момент освобождения удалённого (remotable) объекта на стороне сервера?

Tags: c#, .net-remoting

Удалённый объект с клиентской активацией использует неуправляемые ресурсы, которые необходимо освободить как только объект будет отключён от клиента.

Я реализовал в классе удалённого объекта деструктор, но он не срабатывает ни тогда, когда объект становится недоступен со стороны клиента, ни в обозримом времени после.

Есть ли какой-то вариант, кроме таймера, определить на сервере, что время жизни объекта не продлено спонсором на строне клиента?

Вариант с таймером:

```
        public конструктор или любой другой метод() {
            _lts = (ILease)GetLifetimeService();
            _tmr = new Timer(OnFire, null, 10000, 10000);
        }

        void OnFire(object state) {
            if (_lts.CurrentState == LeaseState.Expired) { _tmr.Dispose(); Dispose(); }
        }
```

P. S. Неуправляемые ресурсы нужно освободить как только, так сразу. В общем, когда у удалённого объекта кончается время жизни, на стороне клиента  ссылка становится null, но на стороне сервера ничего не происходит. Я думал, что там объект убивается, и поэтому решил использовать деструктор, но оказалось, что это не так.

Я думал, что можно вклиниться куда-то в промежуточные объекты, там их много: прозрачный прокси, настоящий прокси, форматировщики и пр. - это со стороны клиента. Со стороны сервера их меньше, но тоже есть. На какой-то картинке я видел на стороне сервера диспетчер, но ни в описании .Net Remoting, ни в описании Remoting API я ничего не нашёл. А думал именно о таком варианте.

Comment: Именно деструктор, а не реализация интерфейса `IDisposable`? А то ведь вызов деструктора в `C#` вообще штука не гарантированная. Безотносительно остального контекста вопроса.

Comment: @CrazyElf Dispose сам по себе тоже не работает, его кто-то должен вызвать.

Comment: @CrazyElf в C# нет деструкторов, совсем.

Comment: Я думаю, что решение с таймером нормальное.

Comment: @aepot деструктор=финализатор, как ты его не обзови.

Comment: Дело в том, что деструктор!=финализатор, это две большие разницы.

Comment: Я изначально не понял, о чём вопрос, думал что про то, как гарантировать очистку ресурсов. А оказалось, что про то, можно ли таймер. Наверное можно и таймер, решать только вам. _Есть ли какой-то вариант, кроме таймера_ - нет. Все варианты, включая таймер, вы придумываете сами.

Comment: @aepot вот с таймером я придумал и спрашиваю, а есть ли какие-то другие варианты? Первое, что напрашивается - это событие изменения 'ILease.CurrentState'

Comment: @aepot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/finalizers: "Finalizers (historically referred to as destructors)".

Comment: Если будет угодно, то семантически деструктор в C# это вся полная реализация `IDisposable` включая финализатор. А физически деструкторов в CLR не существует. Называть финализатор деструктором - ошибка, так как финализатор попросту деструктором не является. Финализатора на объекте физически может вообще не быть, но уничтожается он корректно. Если отсутствие конструктора означает наличие неявного конструктора, то отсутствие финализатора не означает наличие неявного финализатора. На уровне GC объекты бывают финализируемые и нет, что говорит само за себя. Я не знаю, как ещё объяснить.

Comment: @aepot Создатели .NET сделали автоматический сборщик мусора, что привело к тому, что автоматический деструктор (~) вызывается недерминированно. Его назвали финализатором, а для детерминированной части деструктора существует интерфейс IDisposable, который имеет поддержку компилятором посредством ключевого слова using. И смысл всего этого очень простой: когда нужно освободить ресурсы, то не рассчитывайте на финализатор, а освобождайте их явно, например, с помощью реализации интерфейса IDisposable, вызов которого поддерживается using.

Comment: @aepot слова, которые используются в тексте, далеко не всегда используются в значении созвучного термина. В обычном тексте значительно реже, чем в документации. Поэтому не нужно цепляться к каждому слову. Хотелось бы обсудить что-то по существу вопроса.